# Displaying objects other than a volume in the renderer2d

Tags: xtk

I am using the xtk toolkit. Is there a way to render objects other than 1 volume (with a labelmap) in the renderer2d. For example I have been able to add a sphere to the 3d renderer, but not the 2d?

I am trying to build in a simple region of interest function, which looks to an atlas to name the structures found in the ROI and reports them. For this I was thinking of loading the atlas structures as vtk objects and then looping through the points of the sphere and using the pick () object function. Do you think this approach will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this is not possible but it sounds like a great feature to display other structures in 2D. Maybe kind of like widgets.

I think in general this will work (using the pick function for spheres) but if you want it in 2D you gotta change something on the XTK side. The 2d renderers are HTML5 2d canvases and basically load the slice of a volume and just set the image data for each pixel (or incorporate a label map) so some work has to be done there to support spheres etc. Feel free to help :)

Comment: Thanks Haehn, very clear answer. I am very new to javascript and programming in general but xtk is teaching me fast so I hope to contribute in the future. For the moment I am using 3d renderers instead of 2d in order to be able to display all object types.